# Change focus by tabindex in code behind

Tags: asp.net

I have a gridview that has textboxes in the item template.  I dynamically bind their tab index at generation.  The gridview can be anywhere from 1 to 5 rows.  I am working with barcode scan guns, so when they scan a number into the first textbox in the grid, it sends the ENTER key, firing my text changed.  I then want to change the focus to the next textbox in the gridview.

Is there a way I can focus(tabIndex) or something like that?